# ubuntu external ip addres

Tags: networking, apache2, ip

I'm new to ubuntu and I need your help with this,

As you know when you install apache you put the internal ip address in your browser and you get it works, I want as well to access it from somewhere else beside my local network how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have first of all to do a port forwarding in your router that connects to the internet.
You may find your router [here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/) and follow the guide or you can read your routers manual if included or google your router to find some info.

By port forwarding you say to your router "if someone asks something in that port forward the message to this computer"

**Note*** the default port of apache is 80

Then you just need to know your ip address that you can find it in your router's interface or by writing in google "my ip address".

Finally go to your browser and type your ip address like this: `http://77.22.33.44`

Comment: I already did that but this happens check it 149.255.255.242

Comment: Run this command to check in which port apache listens : sudo netstat -anp | grep apache . It should be in the third column